# How to use urlHelper for the following with .net Core 2

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have this in my mvc4 application.

```
 <div class="text-center">
    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.ForgotPassword, "ForgotPassword", new { }, new { @class = "small", @id = "forgot" })
 </div>
```

i am converting this to support with .net core 2.0. i have tried the following,

```
@this.Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account", htmlAttributes: new { })
```

Comment: why downvote for the question? i

Comment: Please check [ask] to see how to ask a good question. While you have shown what you have tried, you haven’t made clear whether that does work or not (we can only guess that it does not work for you), and *why* it does not work. Furthermore, linking to actions is a very basic task that is handled [very early in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view). You haven’t shown anything that suggests that you know what you are actually trying to do (e.g. it’s “ASP.NET Core”, not “.NET Core”, and tagging it with mvc 4 also doesn’ help).

Comment: And as I had to learn just now, you have been discussing this even *before posting the question here* on the ASP.NET Core Slack where you also got a lot feedback that the information you provided simply does not help to diagnose your problem. Yet you haven’t even considered making your question more clear. – I would expect someone with 70k reputation to know a bit better about how to ask a good question than this.

Comment: sure! will do that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, What `Url.Action`  does is generate a URL from action and controller. 
What you are trying to do is generate a `html link or href element`.
So here, You are doing it wrong.
You can achieve it by   -

```
@Html.ActionLink(Strings.ForgotPassword, "ForgotPassword", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "small", @id = "forgot" })
```

or

```
<a href="Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Account")" class="small" id="forgot">@Strings.ForgotPassword</a>
```

both will result in same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the `ActionLink` is not working for you but you can also use `asp-controller` and `asp-action` in asp.net core applications like:

```
<a asp-controller="Account" 
   asp-action="ForgotPassword" 
   class="small" 
   id="forgot">@Strings.ForgotPassword</a>
```

For more details, please refer to the following post:

https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer, this works but the forgotpassword.cshtml is not rendering it says 500

Comment: @Sajeetharan 500 means there is some error or exception probably coming in your controller, put a break point and check where it is breaking